# Estimate of integral of rescaled function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, substitution

We consider a vectorvalued function $v$ on $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}_{x}^n \times \mathbb{R}_{t}$. This function has it's support in $B_{1}(0,0)$ and satisfies the property 
$$\int_{\Omega} |v(x,t)| \: dx dt \geq \alpha |\tilde{v}(x_{0},t_{0})|$$
 Also we consider the rescaled function $v_{r}(x,t) = v(\frac{x-x_{0}}{r},\frac{t-t_{0}}{r})$ which has it's support in $B_{r}(x_{0},t_{0})$. The part that I don't understand is the following:
$$\int_{\Omega} |v_{r}(x,t)| \: dx dt \geq \alpha |\tilde{v}(x_{0},t_{0})| |B_{r}(x_{0},t_{0})|$$
This is what I tried:
Because of the support of $v_{r}$ we can rewrite the integral 
$$\int_{\Omega} |v_{r}(x,t)| \: dx dt = \int_{B_{\mu}(x_{0},t_{0})} |v_{r}(x,t)| \: dx dt$$
Substituting by $\phi(x,t)=(\frac{x-x_{0}}{r},\frac{t-t_{0}}{r})$ gave me
$$\int_{\Omega} |v_{r}(x,t)| \: dx dt = r^2 \int_{B_{1}(0,0)} |v(x,t)| \: dx dt \geq r^2 \alpha |\tilde{v}(x_{0},t_{0})|$$
But I don't manage to get the asked estimate. It would be great if someone could help me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct way to make a change of variables. Think of it this way, you want to transform the current integral into an integral over another set. So, you are looking for a one-to-one  map between the second set and the first set such that there is a bijective vector valued function of new variables $u$ and $m$ from the second set which gives you unique $x$ and $t$ from the first set. So, your substitution should be $$(x,t)=(ur+x_0 , mr+t_0)$$ Note that $ur+x_0$ is a vector and $mr+t_0$ is a number. Calculate the jacobian matrix by expressing the preceding map in terms of vector components and carrying out the appropriate differentiations. You find the jacobian to be $r^{n+1}$. Using the fact that the volumes of $(n+1)$- dimensional balls are proportional to the $n+1$-th powers of their radii, the volume of $B_r(x,y)$ is $|B_1(x,y)|r^{n+1}$, your inequality becomes
$$\int_{\Omega} |v_{r}(x,t)| \: dx dt \geq \frac{\alpha}{|B_1(x_0,t_0)|}|\tilde{v}(x_{0},t_{0})| |B_{r}(x_{0},t_{0})|$$

Comment: Thank you! I understand now the change of variables and how to achieve $r^{n+1}$. But why is $r^{n+1} = |B_{r}(x_{0},y_{0})|$?

Comment: I am not completely sure about your notation, but I assumed that $|B_r(x,y)|$ denotes the volume of the $n+1$ dimensional cube of side length $r$ centred at $(x,y)$. If it has a different meaning then my answer is probably wrong.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have written this. $B_{r}(x_{0},y_{0})$ denotes here the $n+1$-dimensional ball of radius $r$ centered at $(x_{0},y_{0})$.

Comment: $|X|$ denotes the volume of the set X?

Comment: Yes, I guess so, the paper doesn't specify this. So it would be $|B_{r}(x_{0},y_{0})| = \frac{\pi ^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2} +1)} r^{n+1}$

Comment: I already edited the answer accordingly, but the $\alpha$ changes to a new one. Are you sure it is the same?

Comment: In the paper they just say $\alpha$ is a dimensional constant, so they might have changed it without a comment. It makes sense, thank you!!